# How to add floating activity like the "Now Playing Music" in Google Play Music

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, navigation-drawer

Please see this screenshot:

[image: Google play music playing a song]

I want to know what kind of activity is this and how do iI manage the functionalities like touching the view and sliding down makes the view to reside at the bottom?

I am working on a navigation drawer and I want to implement it like the one in the Google Play Music.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called the sliding panel bottomsheet, you can find numerous articles related to this. There is also a third party library [Sliding Panel Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

But I would advise you instead of using library, please read the articles related to coordinator layout and the bottomsheet behaviour integration, kindly go through this [BottomSheet tutorial `CoordinatorLayout`](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066), which you can use as a starting point.

[BottomSheetBehaviour](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior)

[BottomSheet](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b)

[Material documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/)